# Get Cart Item Remove URL in Woocommerce 3.3

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, cart

I've got the below code to get elements from the woocommerce cart, but I can't figure out how to get **remove link of the item** as well. could you help me?

```
<div class="carters">
    <?php

        $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); echo $subtotal;

        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
            $qty        = $cart_item['quantity'];
            $price      = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
            $thumbnail  = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product_id ); 
            echo '<img width="50px" src="' . $thumbnail . '" />';
            $title      = get_the_title( $product_id ); 
            echo $title . $qty . $price; 
        }

    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [`wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key )`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_cart_remove_url.html) function that can be used for that this way:

```
<div class="carters">
    <?php

        $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); echo $subtotal;

        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
            $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
            $qty        = $cart_item['quantity'];
            $price      = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
            $thumbnail  = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product_id ); 
            echo '<img width="50px" src="' . $thumbnail . '" />';
            $title      = get_the_title( $product_id ); 
            echo $title . $qty . $price;

            // get the cart remove url (since WooCommerce 3.3)
            $cart_item_remove_url = wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key );
        }

    ?>
</div>
```

Tested and works on Woocommerce 3.3+

> It replace deprecated [`WC_Cart` method `get_remove_url( $cart_item_key )`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#858-868)

So before woocommerce 3.3 you will use instead:

```
WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key );
```